# Custom XML Attribute Name for XSLT

Tags: angularjs, xml, xslt

I have a XSLT that generate AngularJS, with model='xxx'

Now, I have to make a XSLT to use the same source but the target will be Angular6,

I Change my XSLT to this: (only model to [(model)])

```
<xsl:template name="InputText">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="{@type}" class="form-control {@class}"
    >
    <xsl:attribute name="[(model)]">
         <xsl:value-of select="@model"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
   </input>
</div>
```

But, when I transform I have the following message:

```
FATAL ERROR:  'line 131: You cannot call an attribute '[(model)]''
```

I understand the error, but my question is, I must to use some escape or additional parameter.

Test: My xslt execution is with Java.

Comment: You may need to use alternate syntax. `bindon-model` should be the equivalent attribute name for `[(model)]`; see https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview

Comment: Thanks @TimC, Really, Your help resolve my problem... I have to learn about angular! thanks a lot.